# Check convergence of $\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How can I check the convergence of

$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2-1}$$

? As it's almost the same as

$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}$$

which converges, it should converge, but I can't use a comparison between the two here, as

$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2-1} \geq \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}$$

so it wouldn't help. So how should I go about it?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1624203

Comment: Hint: $k^2-1>(k-1)^2$.

Comment: [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D2%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bk%5E2-1%7D%24) shows more Q&As about this series.

Comment: This user wanted to use the comparison test and not the integral test. Arguably a much easier problem.

Comment: @openproblem: A comparison test solution has been given in the answers to the duplicate target as well. Here is another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3114040

Comment: @MartinR By the way you're really good at finding duplicates. I had you in mind when I posed the question: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33058/how-to-quickly-find-duplicate-questions-which-are-not-exact-duplicates

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for elaborating I'm still trying to understand the duplicate policy. I've only been on a couple weeks or so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\frac 1 {k^{2}-1} \leq \frac 2 {k^{2}}$ for all $k \geq 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $1\leq (\frac{k}{2})^{2}$ for k bigger than 1:

$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2-(\frac{k}{2})^{2}}\geq\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2-1} \geq \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}$$